# How to transform data table columns, indexed by position, by reference?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that houses several columns of `factor`s. I'd like to convert 2 columns originally read as `factor`s to their original numeric values. Here's what I've tried:

```
  data[, c(4,5):=c(as.numeric(as.character(4)), as.numeric(as.character(5))), with=FALSE]
```

This gives me the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(c(4, 5), c(as.numeric(as.character(4)),  :
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 7 items of column 'Bentley (R)' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
2: In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(c(4, 5), c(as.numeric(as.character(4)),  :
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 7 items of column 'Sparks (D)' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
3: In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(c(4, 5), c(as.numeric(as.character(4)),  :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the factor column's underlying type. Character columns are now recommended (can be in keys), or coerce RHS to integer or character first.
4: In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(c(4, 5), c(as.numeric(as.character(4)),  :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the factor column's underlying type. Character columns are now recommended (can be in keys), or coerce RHS to integer or character first.
```

Also I can tell the conversion has not succeeded because the 4th and 5th columns persist in being `factor`s after this code has run.

As an alternate, I tried this code, which won't run at all:

```
 data[, ':=' (4=c(as.numeric(as.character(4)), 5 = as.numeric(as.character(5)))), with=FALSE]
```

Finally, I tried referencing the column names via `colnames`:

```
  data[ , (colnames(data)[4]) := as.numeric(as.character(colnames(data)[4]))]
```

This runs but results in a row of `NA`s as well as the following errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`((colnames(data)[4]), as.numeric(as.character(colnames(data)[4])))) :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the factor column's underlying type. Character columns are now recommended (can be in keys), or coerce RHS to integer or character first.
3: In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`((colnames(data)[4]), as.numeric(as.character(colnames(data)[4])))) :
  RHS contains -2147483648 which is outside the levels range ([1,6]) of column 1, NAs generated
```

**I need to do this by position and not by column name, since the column name will depend on the URL. What's the proper way to transform columns by position using `data.table`?**

I also have a related query, which is how to transform numbered columns relative to other numbered columns. For example, if I want to set the 3rd column to be equal to 45 minus the value of the 3rd column plus the value of the 4th column, how would I do that? Is there some way to distinguish between a real # vs a column number? I know something like this is not the way to go:

```
dt[ , .(4) = 45 - .(3) + .(4), with = FALSE]
```

So then how can this be done?

Comment: Indexing by position is unambiguously bad practice, but go ahead: `dt[,4] <- 45 - dt[[3]] + dt[[4]]`

Comment: Please do *not* use `<-` for adding/updating columns in `data.table`. Use `:=`. It's the idiomatic way. Have you looked at the [new HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to assign by reference and position, you need to get the column names to assign to as a character vector or the column numbers as an integer vector and use `.SDcols` (at least in data.table 1.9.4).

First a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(iris)
DT[, c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length") := list(factor(Sepal.Length), factor(Petal.Length))]
str(DT)
```

Now let's convert the columns:

```
DT[, names(DT)[c(1, 3)] := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), 
   .SDcols = c(1, 3)]
str(DT)
```

Alternatively:

```
DT[, c(1,3) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), .SDcols=c(1,3)]
str(DT)
```

Note that `:=` expects a vector of column names or positions on the left side and a list on the right side.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the suggestion.